# jQuery get text from html tag problems

Tags: jquery, datatable

I am having the following html code stored in a variable `html`:

```
<td class=" sorting_1"><a href="Student/5">James Ford</a></td><td>james@james.com</td><td>-</td>
```

The code is fetched from a DataTable row that is clicked.

I want to get the text of the tags by using jquery like `$('a:first').text()`

But how do I do it from the content of the variable?

So it would be something like `html.$('a:first').text()`

I do not want to make it into a string and split it or something.

/James

Comment: In the first part i somehow understand waht you want to do but in the second part you get really confusing

Comment: $('.sorting_1 > a').first().html(); will geht you the first a tag inside the sorting_1 class and then retreive the inner html of that a tag wich will be "james ford"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do this

```
 $(html).find('a:first').text()
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var html = '<td class=" sorting_1"><a href="Student/5">James Ford</a></td><td>james@james.com</td><td>-</td>';
var $html = $(html);
alert($("a:first", $html).text());
```